# Show the total of rows and columns in jquery full calendar

Tags: jquery, json, fullcalendar

I have a Jquery Full calendar. Values to be displayed inside the full calendar is fetched from json. Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/binoymat/T37Hx/3/)

Full calendar HTML Code

```
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Full Calendar Jquery Code

```
var $calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
},
editable: true,
selectable: true,
selectHelper: true,
defaultView: 'month',
events: [
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 1 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 2 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 3 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 4 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 5 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 6 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 7 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 8 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 9 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 10 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 11 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 12 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 13 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 14 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 15 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 16 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 17 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 18 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 19 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 20 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 21 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 22 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 23 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 24 2015"}

]
});
```

This is What I am looking for:-

I want to calculate the **total of rows and columns** and **display them in a separate div**. Here is the desired output sample of what I am looking for [Desired Output Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8BCr.png)

Is this possible?? Please edit my fiddle for solutions. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/T37Hx/6/)

Working code:

```
var counts = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

var baseEvent = $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'clientEvents')
baseEvent.forEach(function(event) {
    counts[event.start.getDay()] += parseInt(event.title);
});

console.log(counts);
```

Yes you can but you need to define a function which is doing mod 7 to dates.

Algorithm:

```
weekDayList[];

foreach events to event
   date = event.getDate();
   var mod = date.getDay()%7;
   weekDayList[mod].count += event.title;
```

When you do this you got days in a week seperate 7 sections.

Now you can write to html with;

```
weekDayList[0].count
weekDayList[1].count
weekDayList[2].count
weekDayList[3].count
.
.
.
```

Comment: Im new to Jquery, Would be of great help if this change is made to the fiddle

Comment: There is a console.log. I mean you see results on console. On chrome you hit f12 and now you can see the result.

Comment: Oh man you should learn js or jquery for it. Create a div with id = "cols". And $('cols').append('<p>'+counts[0]+'</p>')

Comment: @user5602805 I edited fiddle. You can use it. For rows use event.getWeek(); It will give you 4 row for each week. Can you apply my answer?

Comment: Hmm. For that situation you need to define prev or next button click event. And each click you need to get current Month events and use our function.